# System("pause") isn't working even with correct header

Tags: c++

I'm making this program where I have to use system("pause") a few times in Visual Studio, but whenever I run the code, it doesn't pause at all. I have the `<cstdlib>` header and everything in there. Is there another reason why this wouldn't work? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    int range = (rand() % 5) + 1;
    double start = 0;
    double end = 0;

    cout << "Try to hit the same key within " << range << "seconds.";

    system("pause");
    start = clock();

    system("pause");
    end = clock();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At which OS are you running that program?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Windows?

Comment: @PaulSanders What makes you sure from that question?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Visual Studio?  That's where most people run it...  But I see what you mean.

Comment: @Paul There are other OS where you can use VS Code for example.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, I edited my comment and my answer.

Comment: A description of "wouldn't work" is insufficient.   What input did you provide to the `pause` command?   What behaviour did you ACTUALLY observe?   Does the program behave one way if run within Visual Studio and another way if run from a command prompt?

Comment: @Peter What happens when I run it is that the output window comes up for a split second before going away. It's supposed to display the sentence before and then wait for the user to press the key to start the timer.

Answer (score 1):

"pause" isn't a program you can run by itself, it's a function of the command prompt. If you must do this using a system call, instead run:

`cmd.exe /c pause`

Answer (score 0):

That actually works fine for me (on Windows), but if all you want to do is read a keystroke then try this (should work everywhere):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int range = (rand() % 5) + 1;
    double start = 0;
    double end = 0;

    cout << "Try to hit the same key within " << range << "seconds.";

    int c = getc (stdin);
    start = clock();

    c = getc (stdin);
    end = clock();

    c = getc (stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](http://rextester.com/AQAP8681)